# how to backup SSISDB catalog (not just the DB)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I am not sure if I know what I'm doing: I am trying to backup "Integration Services Catalogs", seen in the picture below.

[image]

But all the instructions I get is to backup the SSISDB database. All I am familiar with is the catalog, that's where I go to "execute" my packages.. **I know executing is just running some commands/script to run SPs within SSISDB database**, but 1) if I was to make a backup of SSISDB, would that also give me a full backup of the catalog too?? How so? So restoring the DB would give me back my catalog ???

If the answer is yes, why do I need to BACKUP MASTER KEY Transact-SQL statement as part of the backup procedure (according to my studies), wouldnt this just be a simple DB backup???
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the catalog is stored in that database, so yes, backing up that database backs up the entire catalog.  Also there is encryption happening in the catalog, so having a backup of the master key makes sense.  But notice that this article states that this is not required.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2012/03/23/ssis-catalog-backup-and-restore/

Comment: " This step is not necessary every time you do backup unless you have lost the file or the password or if you have changed the master key of the SSISDB database. "  ---- It is not required as part of the backup procedure as the OP stated he believe was the case.

Comment: What it is saying is that, you only need to do it once. Any subsequent times, you won't need to back it up. Which is true unless certificate or security settings change.

Comment: Exactly...  It is a necessary component to backups.  It is not required as part of the backup process.